# Android Volley: Perform task after imageload

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

I am using Volley Library to download an image. I want to change the text of a TextView after the image is loaded. Like, before the text is loading. and after the image is loaded it should change to loaded.

```
NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.def);
image.setImageUrl(url, ImageUtil.getImageLoader(getApplicationContext()));
```

How can i listen or call a function when the image is completely loaded?

Comment: Have you tried subclassing `NetworkImageView` and adding an interface as the image loades?

Comment: What is imageView1?  Where is that defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as in code snippet below..

```
ImageView image = ImageView.class.cast(layout.findViewById(R.id...));
    String url = "..."; // URL of the image

    mImageLoader.get(url, new ImageListener() {

                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_error); // set an error image if the download fails
                }

                public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                        image.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(container.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
                        image.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                    } else
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_loading); // set the loading image while the download is in progress
                }
            });
```

you can create your mImageLoader instance as below to implement cache

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        mCache.put(url, bitmap);
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return mCache.get(url);
    }
});'
```

Comment: Will it also cache the image? I need to cache the image too